# channel.connect.failed error when deploy flex/java project to linux redhat server

Tags: java, linux, apache-flex

i keep getting this error ive been looking at it for a day now and im just beat. i was wondering if anyone can help me.
this is the error
**Channel.Connect.Failed error NetConnection.Call.Failed: HTTP: Failed: url: 'http://localhost:8080/Learn/messagebroker/amf'**

when i do this locally on tomcat server on local development  machine it works fine when i brought it over to linux im getting this error.
i dont know what to do anymore it should be straight forward but i'm having no luck. 
i do have a web.xml and i see a broker for my remote access so i just dont know what it could possibly be. i would appreciate any help anyone can offer.
Miguel

Answer (score 0):

ok i figuered it out. when i brougth my project over to linux tomcat expects to see all the java classes, flex config files and web.xml file under the root/web-inf. I wish i can change that but thats just the way it works. I was hoping with blazeds i can just put my files on a server and it would all work but thats not the case so if your like me and are new to the whole blazeds scene. Be careful you will nee to change the server web.xml file along with adding additional files under the ROOT/WEB-INF directory. One thing that helped me alot was the LOG files under tomcat_instal/LOG/logfilename.
Good luck to you